# Can Word automatically find the titles and apply the corresponding style to them?

Tags: html, vba, ms-word, html-to-pdf

I'm desperately trying to convert an html to word or pdf with updated table of contents with page numbers (initially an R-markdown doc -> html).

When opening my HTML to word, the 650 page (!) document does not display page numbers or table of contents, although the titles are saved as titles.
One suggested solution was that the document may have become corrupted during conversion. It was therefore necessary to copy / paste all the text on another document and save it.

Indeed, when I copy and paste the text leaving all styles, pagination is possible.

But I need to have my titles and create an automatic table of contents!
I have the list of titles at the beginning of the document, but they are not identified as titles by Word.

**Could there be a way that Word automatically applies the Heading 1 style to all sentences starting with 1, 2, 3 etc; Heading 2 style to all sentences starting with 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.3 etc. And so on?**

Maybe a Macro ? (I don't know anything about VBA :( )

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use find and replace to do that, no VBA necessary.

Comment: I cannot find and replace all the titles by hand !

Comment: Find and replace is a feature, not a manual process. This is off-topic or a poorly developed question in this forum which is a programming forum. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. This would be appropriate on Super User or Microsoft Answers. http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word

Comment: Can you share  page of your word document, so that it can be downloaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this without using any VBA code just by using Find and Replace, e.g.

[image]

If you don't know how to use wildcards see: https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm